# Edit a variable from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am working on a simple project: Server executes a slave (ReaderF Class) inside a thread that reads a file and then extracts its content and saves it inside the Server himself. The server then needs to execute a pool to  send the content to a client when he connects. I started by writing the ReaderF to extract the content. Problem: it never edits the String variable in which he is supposed to stock the content. Here is what I did:

```
public class Serveur {
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Socket socket;
public String res=null; //This is what my thread is supposed to be editing
ExecutorService pool = null;
public static final int port = 33333;

Serveur(int port, int size){
    try {
        pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, size);            

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Serveur.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

void manage () throws IOException {
    while(true) {
        ReaderF S = null;
        try {
            S = new ReaderF(serverSocket.accept(), this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread t=new Thread(S);
        t.start();

    }
}
```

And this is the slave that reads and edit the res variable.

```
public class ReaderF implements Runnable {

private final Socket socket;
private Serveur serverMaitre;

ReaderF(Socket socket, Serveur serverMaitre) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.serverMaitre = serverMaitre;
}


public void run() {
    String fileName = "/home/abdou/1.txt";
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    Writer output =null;
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
        output = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "8859_1");
      String line;
      String res="";
      while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
          res+=line+"\n";   
      }

      serverMaitre.res=res; // This is where i tell him to edit res inside the server
      socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

When I execute this main I see nothing on the screen. I know that it is due to the fact that the Server is stuck in the while loop.

```
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Serveur serveur = new Serveur(Serveur.port, 1);
    serveur.manage();
    System.out.println("The res variable content is"+serveur.res);

}}
```

How would I get out of it please. And Is my thread really changing the res variable ? Thank you

Comment: If you add after t.start(); line t.join(); you will probably see the result. But then your app will be nothing more than synchronous (join simply wait's up to the end of a thread, so it's like you will run the content of run() method directly). So I can assume that this is not what you wish to have - isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When multiple threads work with the same variables, then they are allowed to work on a local copy of the variable (in their stack) instead of the original variable (in the heap). This means that one thread may not see changes to a variable that another thread did (he is not 'refreshing' its local data), or the other thread is not 'publishing' (technical term: flushing) the updated value. So, when your ReaderF assign a value to 'res', the main thread (which is checking it) might not notice this. Solution: Make the variable `volatile`:

```
public volatile String res=null;
```

This forces the ReaderF to flush the updated value after assigning, and the main thread to refresh it when reading it.

But you might have another problem here, because you have multiple threads that may be all writing the 'res' variable (Depends on how active your socket is). You can get 'lost updates' or other 'race conditions' here. So maybe you even need a `synchronized` somewhere. But it would be too much to explain Multi-Threading here. Please google about it. Multi-Threading is not trivial unfortunately, you cannot just make new threads as you wish and expect everything to work. And adding a volatile is *not* the solution most of the time. It might just be enough for what you wanna do here.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the while loop I guess. The main is stuck in the Server.manage method because it contains a non stopping loop. How would i replace that so the server would stop the while loop when the thread finishes editing the res ?

Comment: right, i didn't even notice that one lol. (The other problem i talked about still exists though, so you should definately make it volatile). To wait until the started thread has finished, just add t.join() after t.start(). It will block until t is finished and then continue. Of course you should take away the while-loop then. Or, put the code from main method into the run method of server. I don't really understand what you want to do here anyway to be honest, what is the purpose of the main thread printing that variable?

Comment: Well, the main goal is to make the Server class launch a ReaderF thread to read a file. then, that thread should send back to the server the content of the file. Next the server should execute a pool to make him send the result to every client that tries to connect.
I started doing the first part which is making the thread read the file and send it back to the server. That printing on the main is just to test whether the variable was edited or not